# Dynamic function definition

Tags: python

In this python script, I execute a python code located in a string, which defines the functions funA and funB. However, it does not recognize them, even though they are defined in dir().

Script:

```
# Load function that transform x and y to the feature space
exec (self.funAString)
print("Dir  ", dir())
# Debug output: Dir   ['funB', 'self']

x = funA(dataset)
```

Python code of funA as string:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def funA(dataset):
   df = dataset["Label"]
   return df
```

We obtain the following error,

```
NameError: name 'funA' is not defined
```

Comment: There will be some specific reasons for why this works the way it does (not), but this is a bad idea overall. If you write the name `funA` in your code, then it should be clear _from the code_ where that name comes from; it should not depend on runtime data. I'd think it a better idea, if you have to have code-as-data at all, to just have the *function body* as data, which `funA` will `exec`, not the function definition itself.

Comment: My answer shows how to do it, but as @deceze said **it's a bad idea**.

I point to the concept of "decorators". This is just to give you some inspiration on how you might achieve your desired behaviour. You might not be able to just use it "as is" though.

Comment: funA (from string) doesn't take arguments, and in script you call it with dataset. :)
Could you create minimalistic code which would actually represent your problem? :)

I've created that and it works: `string_fun = """
def print_test():
    print("test")
"""

exec(string_fun)
print_test()
`

Comment: @ravenwing there's no actual function definition in the question, but I'd agree that that is a problem

Comment: My guess is that you ran the above code within a function and not in the global scope, which makes things more difficult. But you need to show a [reprex].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, that **this is usually a bad idea**. If you want to dynamically change functions, have a look at how ["decorators"](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) change functions for instance.

It seems like you're using this within a method of some class (going by your use of `self`). `exec` will only define `funA` in the current scope. Once you're out of the method, it will be inaccessible.

You can change this, by setting the freshly defined function as a member after the `exec` call.

```py
from textwrap import dedent

class Foo:
    funAString = dedent("""
        def funA():
            return 1
    """)

    def define(self):
        exec(self.funAString)
        self.funA = locals()["funA"]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = Foo()
    x.define()
    print(x.__dict__)
    print(x.funA())  # prints "1"
```

When you're doing this outside a class (or rather in the global scope), you can just use the function as is:

```py
funAString = """
def funA():
    return 1
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exec(funAString)

    x = funA()
    print(x)  # prints "1"
```

Thanks to interjay for pointing to a mistake in my original answer.

Comment: This would work just as well if you just had `x = funA()`.

Comment: @interjay Damn, I didn't know that ... thanks. Gotta revise or delete this answer then

Comment: @interjay amended the answer, should be good now. thanks again for the pointer. In the class example I have to use `locals`. I assume, this is because just using the function would try to look it up in the global scope